# error in tex file generated by stata tabout command

Tags: tables, texdoc, stata

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]

\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {14cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{Sector}} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-14} 
\textbf{Produce\_Full\_SR}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{10}&\textbf{11}&\textbf{12}&\textbf{Total} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2} \cmidrule(l{.75em}){3}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){4}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){5}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){6}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){7}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){8}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){9}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){10}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){11}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){12}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){13}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){14}
&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \%&Col \% \\
\midrule
0&37.5&97.2&96.8&50.0&97.1&71.4&88.1&85.7&93.8&87.7&95.7&91.7&90.6 \\
1&62.5&2.8&3.2&50.0&2.9&28.6&11.9&14.3&6.3&12.3&4.3&8.3&9.4 \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0&100.0 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }sustainability.dta}
\normalsize

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

hello I got this tex file generated by the stata command, texdoc do (2nd code attached), but I dunno what's the problem. I added the rotating feature/sidewaystable because I thought it couldn't fit; but the problem seems to be something else--the error displayed by Overleaf I couldn't understand at all=( Can someone help me, thanks a lot! I am a newbie in latex ^^

The stata code:

```
texdoc init top.tex, replace force
/*tex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {#} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
\toprule
tex*/


texdoc init bot.tex, replace force
/*tex
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }#}
\normalsize
\end{center}
\end{document}
tex*/


tabout Produce_Full_SR Sector using "$tables\table_overview.tex", ///
        c( col ) f( 1 ) clab(Col_%) ///
        rep ///
        style(tex) bt font(bold) cl1(2-14) cl2(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14) ///
        topf(top.tex) botf(bot.tex) topstr(14cm) botstr(sustainability.dta)
```

The error by overleaf from running the tex code is:

[image]

and many other errors which I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 1):

`\cmidrule` spans at least one column, e.g., `\cmidrule{1-1}`, but you have two many `\cmidrule{i}` with `i` from 2 to 14 with a single scalar input to `\cmidrule` instead of a range..

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]

\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {14cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
\toprule
                           & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{Sector}} \\
\cmidrule{2-14} 
\textbf{Produce\_Full\_SR} & \textbf{1}                              & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{11} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{Total} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-2} \cmidrule(l{.75em}){3-3}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){4-4}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){5-5}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){6-6}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){7-7}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){8-8}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){9-9}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){10-10}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){11-11}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){12-12}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){13-13}\cmidrule(l{.75em}){14-14}
                           & Col \%                                  & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%     & Col \%      & Col \%      & Col \%      & Col \% \\
\midrule
0                          & 37.5                                    & 97.2       & 96.8       & 50.0       & 97.1       & 71.4       & 88.1       & 85.7       & 93.8       & 87.7        & 95.7        & 91.7        & 90.6 \\
1                          & 62.5                                    & 2.8        & 3.2        & 50.0       & 2.9        & 28.6       & 11.9       & 14.3       & 6.3        & 12.3        & 4.3         & 8.3         & 9.4 \\
\textbf{Total}             & 100.0                                   & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0      & 100.0       & 100.0       & 100.0       & 100.0 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }sustainability.dta}
\normalsize

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```